# Threading / Lock issue in Sitecore 8.1

Tags: glass-mapper

We had production outage on 11/7/2017 and accordingly I registered a ticket with sitecore support team and provided memory dump. Based on memory dump files here is their response:

All three memory dump files indicate the same problem. A lot of requests are stuck trying to acquire a lock:

```
System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(System.Object)
Glass.Mapper.IoC.AbstractConfigFactory`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].GetItems()
Glass.Mapper.AbstractService..ctor(Glass.Mapper.Context)
```

The strange thing is that none of these memory dump files contain a thread that owns the lock.I recommend to contact GlassMapper developer team.Maybe they can explain why all threads are waiting to acquire a lock even though it is free.

Did anyone face this issue?

Thanks!

**UPDATE 11/15/2017 : Error message during outage**

```
1380 11:13:47 INFO  [Brandify] GetNearestRestaurants Time elapsed: 146ms.
4680 11:13:47 ERROR System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
    at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
       at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
```

Comment: What version of the GlassMapper are you using?  We may need to inspect the source at GitHub.

Comment: It's 4.0.11.63 version but as I said I'm not sure if posted exception is related to glass mapper but that is the one exception which I got during two outage

Comment: I don't see this going anywhere; it is basically a "why isn't this working?" question, with no example code or any further insight. Please take this to Slack or Community, for further discussion.

Comment: @MarkCassidy
Unfortunately I don't have much details on this I posted the response which I got from sitecore support...and I will further check on community on this...thanks

Comment: based on this question and another about locking issues in this class we are looking to move locks in the next release. There is currently a beta package that contains this change. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Glass.Mapper.Sc/4.4.1.329-beta

Comment: thanks @MichaelEdwards for this update...so running version in out project is Glass.Mapper.Sc.ll( 4.0.11.63 ) for this as suggested we'll use package manager utility to install this version on local machine and then we will get latest Glass.Mapper.Sc.ll( 4.4.1.329-beta ) in project.

Do we need to change any glass mapper code for this update or we can directly replace this latest dll on higher env. ( staging , prod )

Comment: The only other change made was to the GlassMapperScCustom class whcih should be in your App_Start folder: https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/blob/develop/Source/Glass.Mapper.Sc/App_Start/GlassMapperScCustom.cs.pp#L18. Make sure that this line is added. Also download version 4.4.1.331-beta, it has a couple more fixes.

Comment: Sure @MichaelEdwards I'll move this change on Prod and will track site performance further....meanwhile can you please provide your vote to reopen this issue as I got solution

Comment: @MichaelEdwards Is that GlassMapper version 4.4.1.331-beta is compatible with Sitecore 8.1 
and with this new version Do we need to update overall glass mapper api code change in all .cshtml in projects